# Looking to confirm inequality or learn where mistake is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

Hello I am looking for some advice on the following,

I am wanting to show that $n^{\frac{1}{n}} \lt (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

and I thought I would try by induction

The base case of n=1 is clear because $1 \lt 4$

Now I said suppose it holds that

$$n^{\frac{1}{n}} \lt (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{2}$$

then I must show this implies the truth of

$$(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \lt (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})^{2}$$

I used Bernoulli to show that $(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}^{n+1} \gt \sqrt{n+1}$ for all n and then I thought if I can just use that and show that $\sqrt{n+1} \gt (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ then my proof would be complete.

Any advice guys? How does it look? I tried to do as much as I can on my own as I do want to learn, but I also dont want to be coming up with false proofs etc

Here is my new way of saying it,

We already showed base case,

now suppose that $$n^{1/n} \lt (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{2}$$

Then we want to show   $$(n+1)^{1/(n+1)} \lt (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})^{2}$$

I then use $$(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})^{2} \ge 1+2\sqrt{n+1} \gt \sqrt{n+1} \gt (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$ to show it holds,

how does this seem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, except you have not written out the steps cleanly.  As I understand, you want to use induction and hence the inductive step
$$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)^2 > (n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}} \iff \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)^{n+1} > \sqrt{n+1}$$
Where the last step can be proved using Bernoulli's inequality.

---

Of course it is simpler to use Bernoulli directly and avoid induction altogether.  The original inequality, by raising both sides to the power $\dfrac{n}2$,  is equivalent to
$$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n> \sqrt{n}$$

and that is easily concluded by Bernoulli which in fact gives the tighter $LHS > 1+\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I added to my post some more of me attempting the first way

Answer (score 2):

Applying the AM-GM inequality:

$\sqrt[n]{n} = \sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}}\leq \dfrac{n-2+2\sqrt{n}}{n}<1+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}}<1+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{1}{n}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2$

Comment: Hmm, is there a way I could do the problem without this, or derive it as I go. I would prefer if possible to do it with just what I had put, and using what I showed from Bernoulli

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Equivalently we want to show that $n\lt \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n}$.

For $n\ge 2$, use the first three terms of the binomial expansion of $\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n}$.

Comment: I'll try that thanks , does my way of comparing sqrt of n+1 not work ?

Comment: The inequality $\sqrt{n+1}\gt (n+1)^{1/(n+1)}$ certainly holds for $n\gt2$. But I don't see immediately how that can be used to push through the induction step. However, there may be a way to do it. But taking the first three terms of the binomial expansion does work. If you run into difficulties (unlikely) I can write a line or two giving the details.

Comment: Thanks I will work on it tomorrow and post my results

Comment: I added to my post some more of my attempt

Comment: Now it is fine. Note that your proof is a "fake" induction in the sense that you have not used the truth of the "$n$" case to deduce the truth of the $n+1$ case. While it still is in principle a legal induction, it is better to write it up as a non-induction argument.

Comment: Yes I did notice that, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the "accept,"  which should probably be reversed. The answer by Macavity  proves the result by a direct appeal to Bernoulli, which is what you were looking for (and also found).